# Complex superscript in LaTeX

Tags: latex

How to get this result in LaTeX?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
$\mathbb R^{N_g\times T}$
\end{document}
```